# How to convert an array object to a string in typescript constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I started learning Angular 2 with basic knowledge on typescript. So, I tried to work out code using constructor. But I'm getting type error in the VS Code editor and also unable to get the expected output in the browser. I am sharing the code below and attaching the screenshot too. It would be very helpful if anyone tell me how to convert the Object in the Array to a string in the typescript constructor?

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  heroes: Array<Hero>;
  myHero: string;

  constructor() {
    this.title = "Tour Of Heroes";
    this.heroes = [
      new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'),
      new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
      new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
      new Hero(20, 'Tornado')
    ];
    this.myHero = this.heroes[0];
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHo3C.png)
[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCKHL.png)

---

Author provided code copied from comment:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
<p>Heroes:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"> {{ hero }} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What value do you want to store in myHero?

Comment: You should display a property of `Hero` not the object itself. As for the array you need to iterate over it and display a property of it. If you want more help then show your template (html) file.

Comment: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
<p>Heroes:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ul>`

Comment: @Kumar - see my latest edit underneath, I use your template you provided in your comment. By the way, you should edit your question to provide any requested data instead of providing it in a comment. Use the edit button.

Comment: Once the 15 minutes period has expired please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Comment: @Igor. Maybe he is new to SO. He still doesn't know about accepting answer... So let him learn it gradually....

Comment: Thank you @Igor for suggesting the edit feature. Just now I found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.myHero = this.heroes[0].name; // display the name
```

Or if you want to keep your selected hero as an object then display the name in the template.

*app.component.html*

```
{{myHero.name}}
```

As for the array you need to loop over it and display something interesting on the object from the array itself.

```
<div *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

---

From your comment, here is your fixed code that displays the name of the myHero instance and from loop over the heros array.

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero.name}}</h2>
<p>Heroes:</p>
<ul> <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"> {{ hero.name }} </li> </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: @Kumar - glad you got it working and cool you are following the tutorial, the angular2 team did a great job on it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning **Hero class** object(s) to **string variable** which is not **compatible**. So, rather than changing it to **string**, declare it with ***Hero class type***.  So,

```
myHero: string;
```

change it to

```
myHero: Hero;
```

And in template use it with property like,

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero.name}}</h2>
      <p>Heroes:</p>
         <ul>
             <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"> {{ hero.name}} </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I worked on that previously but unable to get the browser output. The interpolation data binding displays [object Object]

Comment: [object Object] means it holds some properties. So you should use `.property` with object like `{{object.property}}` so use it like---- `{{myHero.id}}` or `{{myHero.name}}`

Comment: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
<p>Heroes:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    {{ hero }}
  </li>
</ul>`

Comment: Please take a look at the code written without constructor [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html). Through this code I'm getting required output without changing the interpolation data binding from {{myHero}} to {{myHero.id}}. Please compare the code with mine and please explain.

Comment: What to compare? You need to understand diff between variable and object. variable holds single value and object holds property.  `{{myHero}}` represents a variable which can hold a single value eg. `constructor{ this.myHero="windstrom"}`. This will display `windstrom` on the screen. Now if you assing it an object like `constructor{this.myHero={id:"1",name:"windstrom"}}` then `{{myHero}}` will display `[object Object]` so you have to use myHero with property like `{{myHero.name}}`

Comment: Thank you so much. My mistake is i didn't updated in the html file. Your direction helped me to figured out the mistake I made. And @Igor shared another approach to my question.  

this.myHero = this.heroes[0].name; // display the name

Comment: Ok Cheers ! Enjoy Angular2 !